# Prove that D2n has an element of order p.

Tags: group-theory

I know D2n is the group of symmetries of a regular n-gon. Also I know that |D2n| = 2n.

Suppose that p|2n for some prime p. Prove that D2n has an element of order p.

I can do this by appealing to Cauchy’s Theorem but is there a way to do this directly as in by finding the required element?

Answer (score 0):

If $p=2$, any flip (reflection) generates a subgroup of order $2$.

If $p$ is odd, then necessarily $p$ divides $n$.  So then a rotation through $\frac{n}{p}$ vertices generates a subgroup of order $p$.